# StrConv() corrupting strings on Windows 2008 server

Tags: encoding, character-encoding, vb6, windows-server-2008, codepages

I'm trying to migrate a web application from a windows 2008 vps to a dedicated windows 2008 vps ( both 32bit edition ). The problem i noticed ( and i've fighting with it for more than 24 hours as of now ) is that most of the text comes in a garbled form ( and this ruins all of the application ). the app works like this: (html+js) -> php -> vb6 dll -> reply.

Initially i thought it must be an issue with encoding and iis but i think this is not the case. I narrowed down the problem to this:

when functions of the .dll are called, the string parameters of the functions are first parsed and translated to a vb6 proper format:

```
Public Function getCorrectStringNoTrans(ByVal strWord As String) As String

    If strWord <> "" Then
        If isUTF8 = False Then
            strWord = Trim$(strWord)
        Else
            Open "c:\log.txt" For Output As #1
            Dim lol As Integer
            For lol = 1 To Len(strWord)
                Print #1, "bef:" & lol & ":" & Mid$(strWord, lol, 1) & ":" & AscW(Mid$(strWord, lol, 1)) & ":" & Asc(Mid$(strWord, lol, 1))
            Next lol

            strWord = StrConv(strWord, vbFromUnicode)

            For lol = 1 To Len(strWord)
                Print #1, "aft:" & lol & ":" & Mid$(strWord, lol, 1) & ":" & AscW(Mid$(strWord, lol, 1)) & ":" & Asc(Mid$(strWord, lol, 1))
            Next lol
            inData = strWord

            Dim c As New crc
            Dim lll As Long
            lll = UBound(inData)
            Print #1, c.CRC32(inData, lll)
            Close #1

            strWord = Trim$(ConvertUtf8BytesToString(inData))
            '''strWord = Replace$(Trim$(ConvertUtf8BytesToString(inData)), "\'", "'")
        End If
    End If

    getCorrectStringNoTrans = strWord

End Function
```

So in live machine 1 ( the current one, which works properly ) the output for a specific string is ( the last number is a crc check ) :

```
bef:1:Ξ:926:206
bef:2:Ί:906:186
bef:3:Ξ:926:206
bef:4:±:177:177
bef:5:Ξ:926:206
bef:6:»:187:187
bef:7:Ο:927:207
bef:8::140:140
bef:9:Ο:927:207
bef:10:‚:8218:130
aft:1:?:-17714:63
aft:2:?:-20018:63
aft:3:?:-17458:63
aft:4:?:-29489:63
aft:5:?:-32049:63
 1958248078
```

but in the new machine the output is:

```
bef:1:Ξ:926:206
bef:2:Ί:906:186
bef:3:Ξ:926:206
bef:4:±:177:177
bef:5:Ξ:926:206
bef:6:»:187:187
bef:7:Ο:927:207
bef:8::140:140
bef:9:Ο:927:207
bef:10:‚:8218:130
aft:1:?:16191:63
aft:2:?:-20161:63
aft:3:?:-17601:63
aft:4:?:16191:63
aft:5:?:-32193:63
 523875602
```

so ascw() shows that the string gets messed up after strconv() in the **new machine** i'm trying to migrate to.

i have triple-checked the settings in control panel -> regional and language options and all settings are the same in BOTH machines:

formats tab: current format:  greek

location tab: current location: greece

administrative tab: language for non-unicode programs: greek

Then i thought that maybe it's an issue with SP2, because the correctly working machine was sp2, and this one i'm experimenting was sp1, so i updated but alas, no results.

I don't understand why strconv() doesn't work as it should. Maybe I'm missing something in the settings or installation. Any ideas would be highly appreciated.

p.s. it also works correctly in a windows xp development machine with iis5.

Comment: Also, check out `Option Explicit` and make sure you declare all your variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that despite the fact that I have set **language for non unicode programs** to Greek ( codepage 1032 link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb964664.aspx ), both:

```
Private Declare Function GetThreadLocale Lib "kernel32" () As Long
Private Declare Function GetUserDefaultLCID Lib "kernel32" () As Long
```

return 1033 ( US english ) in that specific box for UNKNOWN reasons. In the live box there is no such issue despite it being the same OS and settings

So what I did is change from :

```
strWord = StrConv(strWord, vbFromUnicode)
```

to

```
strWord = StrConv(strWord, vbFromUnicode, 1032)
```

and it works now.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be misunderstanding the encoding.If you're passed a string via COM, then it will already be unencoded and "raw" unicode (UCS-2) string.
If you're being passed in UTF-8 you CAN NOT store it in a string until it's been decoded otherwise it will be corrupted.
You must read non ANSI data as a byte array and decode as appropriate.

VB6 also has no native support for UTF-8. `StrConv()` with `vbUnicode` and `vbFromUnicode` are converting between byte arrays containing ANSI/MBCS data to VB strings in UCS-2.

In summary, assuming you are correctly being passed strings via COM, then the entire function can be replaced with `Trim$()`.

Comment: as you can see from my code after strconv() i'm using ConvertUtf8BytesToString() taken from here: http://www.nonhostile.com/howto-convert-byte-array-utf8-string-vb6.asp  the issue is not that. If what you said was the problem, it wouldn't be working for more than a year now...

Comment: I have no problem with our current live machine ( windows2008 ) server VPS, it's been working as a charm, strconv() produces the different results in a NEW machine i'm trying to set it up...

Comment: It's not working, it WILL be corrupting the strings in various locales. Only the English/American locales will "work" fully. Your code is doing: 1) conversion from a VB6/UCS-2 string to MBCS, with local codepage (potential for corruption, this is unsafe) 2) conversion of the MBCS string from UTF-8 (which it isn't) back to a VB6/UCS-2 string (guaranteed corruption, regardless of codepage). `StrConv()` converts to/from the local codepage in MBCS so will produce different results in different codepages.

Comment: If that is so, why it has been working for more than a year in 2 boxes ? ( win2008 32bit and win xp ). I just tried passing strword as byte array directly to ConvertUtf8BytesToString() without the intervention of strconv() and it doesn't work at all.

Comment: Because `strWord` won't be UTF-8. I am assuming it's passed in as COM and that `ConvertUtf8BytesToString()` is actually doing what it says. You've not clarified or refuted that yet.

Comment: I used GetThreadLocale() and I just found out that in the win xp box AND the current live box ( win2008 ) the localeID is 1032. However, in the NEW win2008 box, the getthreadlocale() says 1033. I modificated the code to be : strWord = StrConv(strWord, vbFromUnicode, 1032 ) and it works now. But your logic seems to be right and I don't see why should be working.

Comment: according to this : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb964664.aspx localeid 1033 is English United States. But like i said i've already set language for non unicode programs to be Greek. Hmmm..

Comment: Personally, I'd remove that entire block, depending on where you're getting the string from.

Comment: so you're saying the best option would be for the dll to receive the parameter as a (utf8) byte array then transform it into a ucs2 byte array and then to ucs2 string ?